# Create MDF copy of SQL server database

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a WPF application connected to WCF services linked to SQL Server through Entity Framework.
I'm trying to copy my sql server database structure into an MDF file so I can work locally but I can't find how to do this...
I can create MDF file but I don't know how to get the database structure into it.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: You can backup the database and restore it on your machine, or detach the file, copy it then reattach it to your local machine. MDF isn't a file you can create with `File >New`

Comment: Another option for local work is to import the database as a database project in [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt). This way, you can even check in the database in a version control system along with the application.